# Copyright issues in apps

Tags: halacha, technology, choshen-mishpat-civil-law, pictures, intellectual-property

Are there be any Halachik issues with regard to using someone else's logo, twitter avatar or the like as part of an app?

If it would be okay, would that only be if I don't make any money from the app?

Comment: Is doing that even legal?

Comment: @DoubleAA, I doubt it. At least the way it's presented here. It might be under certain limited circumstances, but I think this question is out of scope because 1)the legality might impact the Halachah, and the former is not clear in the question, and 2)it's asking for Psak.

Comment: @SethJ As with all choshen mishpat questions, this one can be answered from the POV of straight Ch"M theory, or from the POV of contemporary application, which would have to take the contemporary legal environment into account. So, I don't think (1) makes it out-of scope. I believe that msh210's edit makes it no longer a request for pesak. I'm therefore voting to leave open.

Answer (score 0):

To reiterate:

The opinion of Rabbi Moshe Feinstein and Rabbi Shlomo Zalman Auerbach is that infringing on intellectual property is a violation of *hasagat gevul* -- competing with someone in an unfair way -- and thus prohibited.

I am not an intellectual property lawyer, but I'm strongly inclined to say that whatever you have in mind, if it's legal in your country (assuming your country has solid intellectual-property protections), halacha would allow it as well. If it's illegal in your country, it would also be prohibited by halacha, both out of *dina demalchuta dina* (respecting the law of the land) and *hasagat gevul*.

So please contact appropriate sources as to the legality of your intellectual-property question.